# Filters are missed in Admin Panel

Tags: adminhtml, filter, search

For some reason filters in Admin Panel are missed. I tried to debug it but it is without any result. Can someone say where this collection is prepared or maybe why is it happens?
[image]

Comment: is this you custom module?

Comment: No. Filters for all grids for example Products, Orders or Customers.

Comment: all columns are showing in Grid?

Comment: Any exception.log or system.log ?

Comment: All columns are visible. Only filters is missed.

Comment: No error in logs

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush